# How can I position an image relatively to the boundries of another image?

Tags: javascript, css, http

I am trying to make a rudimentary videogame, with a playground, and a Player Character(PC) that moves in it. My problem is that, though the PC exists as a  inside the the Playground  , it interprets the "left" attribute realtive to the whole page instead of the playground, which means it gets off center if the window gets resized.
Note that the PC is called "Atlas" in the code

presently the playground is made like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body onLoad="begin()">
    <div id = "PlaygroundWrapper">
        <div id = "Playground" onLoad="drawAtlas()">
            <!-- here the DrawAtlas function shuld crate an element -->
            <!-- <div id =  "Atlas"></div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the Player Character is drawn so:

```
var AtlasNode = null;
var ATLAS_ID = 'Atlas';

function drawAtlas() {
    if (AtlasNode === null){
        AtlasNode = document.createElement('div');
        AtlasNode.setAttribute('id', ATLAS_ID);
        playground.appendChild(AtlasNode);
    }
    //ATLAS_WIDTH and _HEIGHT are the size of the PC
    //atlasX and atlasY are the coordinate of the PC
    AtlasNode.style.left = (atlasX-ATLAS_WIDTH/2)+ 'px';
    AtlasNode.style.top = (atlasY-ATLAS_HEIGHT/2) + 'px';
}
```

And this is the stylesheet

```
#Playground{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    padding:0px;
    cursor: none;
    background:#FFD700;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 50px #808080;
}

#Atlas{
    size: 30x30;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url('./img/atlas.jpg');
    position: absolute;
    left: 270px;
    top: 570px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 
position: relative to the #playground

position absolute positions the element absolute inside the next relative positioned parent which in your case might be